# Avoid / Non-capture non printable Unicode characters regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse some logs with non printable Unicode characters in the file:

```
02 Aug 2018 18:00:00,531 ^[[32m[TEXT]^[[m  (ussouth-dc2-ms-2012) This.is.test.log: Service is responding normal
```

How can I avoid `^[[32m` and `^[[m`?

```
^([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s(?:\^\[\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\^\[\[m)\s(.*)
```

My current regex is treating them as normal characters which seems to work fine with I copy paste in online regex tested but when I use the system regex (possibly using java) it fails to parse which is because the file contains non-printable Unicode character.

Comment: post the **exact** error message you are getting as an **edit** to your question because more likely case is you are missing double escape sequences. to match a backslash you have to escape it twice resulting in 4 backslash characters to match a literal backslash.

Comment: `^[` is the character representation of an *escape* character (`\u001B`), which is a non-printable character. The actual text is `\u001B[m`, not `^[[m`.

Comment: @Andreas How the secong set of non-capturing group and capturing group will look like 
(?:\^\[\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\^\[\[m)

Comment: To match `\u001B[m`, use regex `" ... \u001B\\[m ... "`

Comment: @Andreas this is for the last part \u001B[m matches ^[[m , what about the first part ^[[32m ?

Comment: Did you write the original regex? If so, you should be able to add the extra pattern to allow `32` in the regex I showed.

Comment: @Andreas Yes,I wrote the original regex , does this look right ```(?:\u001B\\[m\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\u001B\\[m\[m)``` to match ```[TEXT]``` and avoid ```^[[32m``` and `^[[m```

Comment: Do you need something that matches any ANSI escape sequence, or just those two specific ones?

Comment: I said `\u001B\\[m`, so why do you say `\u001B\\[m\[m`? --- How did adding match for `32` (or any 2 digits) to `\u001B\\[m` become `\u001B\\[m\[[0-9]{2}m)`? --- Why the extra `\[` and the extra `m`? --- Do you even understand the constituent parts of `\u001B\\[m`, i.e. `\u001B` (match escape char), `\\[` (match open bracket), and `m` (match letter `m`)?

Comment: @Andreas I am new to regex so trying my best , all I want is ```^[[32m``` and ```^[[m``` to be non-capturing group and only TEXT is captured.
```(?:\u001B\\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\u001B\\[m)``` is the corrected one

Comment: Let me re-phrase: `^[[32m` is *fake*. That is *not* the text your code sees. The `^[` at the beginning is a *printable representation* of an ESCAPE character, which is a non-printable character. The Java equivalent in a string literal is `\u001B`. So, if your original regex works fine with the fake text containing `^[`, then replacing `\^\[` with `\u001B` in the regex will correct the regex to work with the *real* text.